# Is the flow velocity above or below the inclined plane high? Why?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

There is an inclined plane between the two plates. The fluid flows between the plates. Is the flow velocity above or below the inclined plane high? Why?
[image]
As shown in the figure, the blue line segment is inclined plane, the two black lines are plates, and the red arrow represents the flow direction.

Comment: For completeness you should describe the fluid viscosity and compressibility because they affect the flow pattern, the forces and the pressures.

Comment: What you've drawn is essentially just an airfoil in a wind tunnel. Why would you expect any big differences from a simple airfoil case?

Comment: @D.Halsey This is different from the wing in the wind tunnel. Generally, the wing in the wind tunnel is relatively large, while the wing is relatively small. In my case, the wing is relatively large compared with the wind tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

Above the plate, pressure increases from left to right.  Below the plate pressure drops from left to right. There will be a twisting force on the plate.

The incoming and outgoing flows will curve because of the pressure differentials between top and bottom.

This will increase the flow over the plate and reduce the flow under it, making the overall pressure over the plate lower than that under it.

Comment: You mean that the velocity above is greater than the velocity below?

Comment: Yes - because the pressure on the upstream side is greater under the plate than above it, so the incoming flow will curve upwards, meaning the top channel gets preferential treatment; and at the downstream end the top flow is helped again by the lower pressure of the bottom flow.

Comment: Can you describe it in a streamline image?

Comment: Is the flow greater on the top than on the bottom?

Comment: Sorry - if you need more help you need a better helper.  Try drawing H in the wide ends and L in the low ends of the gaps and draw your own stream lines. Google Bernoulli and stream lines for starters.

Comment: Streamline diagram is to better think about this phenomenon.

Comment: Is the pressure at the top left the same as the pressure at the bottom left?